How can I configure Microsoft Excel to load an add on at launch for all users on a group of computers?
Essentially, I need to set up excel to load add-ons (Analysis Toolpak) on launch for every user on a computer (for the entire lab) at work.
How can I do that if I only have access to group policy or powershell?
I have been banging my head on the wall about this for a minute which is why I'm posting about it.
I don't know all of the users of the computers ahead of time, and ideally this will need to apply retroactively to current users and proactively to future ones.

Start with how to do it without Group Policy. Does it change or add registry values? Does it copy files to the Excel startup folder? After you identify that, then you can assess if it can be automated using Group Policy.

From what I understand Greg, it creates a registry key under the current user hive under Software/Microsoft/Office/[version]/Excel/options called Open.
